# Generating UML Class diagrams in VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, uml

I read that VS 2010 supports modelling projects in UML. Is it possible to generate UML diagrams from already existing code. If so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was answered here: [reverse-engineering-code-into-a-uml-class-diagram-in-vs-2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281419/reverse-engineering-code-into-a-uml-class-diagram-in-vs-2010)

Answer (score 1):

You can now create UML class diagrams from code by using the [Visualization and Modeling Feature Pack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ff655021.aspx) for Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate.