# creating class diagram vs2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, class-diagram

i am currently working on a project using visual studio 2008, vc++.
i want to view the class diagram of my code, but i dont see any "class diagram" option when i click add new item, 
please do help me..
thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Class diagrams and not supported for C++, only C# and VB. Sorry. It's a Visual Studio limitation.

Comment: thanks, but is there any tool that i can use to view the class diagram of my project..?

Comment: Rational Rose, Enterprise Architect, Borland Together

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio doesn't provide a class digram for C++. There are a plethora of UML tools available (and maybe some pre-IBM-hegemony notations) available which will, to varying degrees, reverse engineer object oriented C++.

Comment: hi..could u give me an example of a few..?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[uml]+reverse+engineer has many questions asking much the same, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UML_tools has a list of all tools I've heard of. I'm not aware of any which handle template metaprogramming very well. This question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281419/reverse-engineering-code-into-a-uml-class-diagram-in-vs-2010 is similar to yours but relating to VS 2010