# Visual Studio generate code from UML diagrams?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, uml, generated-code

I'm doing research on producing code from UML diagram using Visual Studio 2015. From what I have done, I have created Use case, Activity, Sequence and Class diagram before generating the code.

When I generate the code, I see that Visual Studio only takes my class diagram to be referred to when it generates the code.

So my question, is it true that Visual Studio will only refer to the class diagram when generating the code?

If not, which means that the way I'm doing the other diagram is wrong (the way I'm using the tools is wrong) what other diagram will it pull?

P/s. Imo, I've done enough googling before asking this question here, results from google also seems to say that Visual Studio only takes class diagram but I did not see any official documentation that states that hence I'm asking this question here.

Thank you in advance for helping.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for the late response, but yes, you can generate code, specifically C# code, only from UML class diagrams. Here's the topic for that:

[Generate code from UML class diagrams](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff657795(v=vs.140).aspx)

FYI, I currently work on Microsoft Azure, so a few years have passed since I worked on class diagrams.